# Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am trying to connect to mysql database. I am using MySQL workbench. These are my codes:

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/try?" +"user=jenny&password=perez");

 PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM address");
 ResultSet myRS=ps.executeQuery();
```

What's wrong with my codes?

Comment: Because you don't have the MySQL JDBC driver on the app's classpath?

Comment: Have you added the `JDBC` driver to your `classpath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes are correct. You come up with that error because you have no mysql connector. Try to download mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin. Install it here C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib. Then, Go to the properties of your project, then follow these:

Go to Libraries, then Compile, click Add JAR/Folder, then search the mysql connector you installed. Then run your program. ^_^

Comment: Could you possibly name a version that isn't several years out of date? The current version is 5.1.34.